# ImageIO: CGImageRead_mapData 'open' failed error = 2

Tags: ios, uibutton, uiimage

In my app, I load images from the disk to use as UIBUtton thumbnails.

To get the image I override the thumbnailImage property's getter, of my Drawing object, to load the image from disk:

```
- (UIImage *)thumbnailImage {

    if (_thumbnailImage) {
        return _thumbnailImage;
    }

    NSString *thumbnailImagePath = [[self getFullPathWithDataFilename:NO] stringByAppendingPathComponent:kThumbImageFileName];

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:thumbnailImagePath]) {
        _thumbnailImage = [[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:thumbnailImagePath] retain];

        return _thumbnailImage;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

I then load the thumbnail into each of my buttons like so:

```
[button setImage:drawing.thumbnailImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

After this point the button is added to the view and works fine. However, if I move the file that the thumbnail image was created from, I get the following error (twice) when I click the button:

```
ImageIO: CGImageRead_mapData 'open' failed '/var/mobile/Applications/F07CB571-4AAA-47E2-B3EB-3D4523AE7B51/Library/root.stack/C1199105-062F-40A3-B56C-3BB1106AC003.drawing/thumbImage.png'
         error = 2 (No such file or directory)
```

This does not crash the app and the thumbnail still displays, however I would like to clear up this issue so the error is not thrown.

I'm thinking that the UIImage is hanging onto a reference to the file it was created from. I've tried breakpointing this as well and cannot identify any specific line of code that causes the error.

Comment: What's the definition and property for thumbnailImage? And your @synthesize is `thumbnailImage = _thumbnailImage`?

Comment: `@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *thumbnailImage;` and yes `@synthesize thumbnailImage = _thumbnailImage;`

Comment: The retain is not needed in that case, assigning the value does the retain. What happens in your action method for the button?

Comment: The button displays the fullImage of the drawing object in a UIView: 
    `if (self.drawingView.hidden) {
        [self.drawingView setImage:drawing.fullImage];
        self.drawingView.hidden = NO;
        self.drawingView.alpha = 0.0;
        
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
            self.drawingView.alpha = 1.0;
        }];
    }`

Comment: Have you fixed this issue? I am running on this same issue.

Comment: I'm also running into this, any news?